# XPath ElementNotVisibleError SeleniumBasic ChomeDriver AutoHotkey ahk

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, autohotkey

I am automating a process in Chrome, but my script can't find the element. I have double checked the XPath with DevTools, and it is the correct Path.

The element is **not** in a iframe, it is nested inside a Div.

I am using the Selenium.keys.Control method to ctrl click on a link. I can click on the element by using the javascriptExecutor ("arguments[0].click();", var), but I have not found a way to ctrl click using the Executor.

Comment: Have you tried to `Actions actions = new Actions(driver); actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).click(element).build().perform();`?

Comment: I was just about to do it, I dappled in it before, but it did not seem to work. I will try again. Thanks mate :) Have a great day

Comment: @DilipMeghwal Do you know if I can use JavascriptExecutor in a Actions stream? I think that would solve my issue. It seems like the Web dev's messed up the code and is blocking an element with a parent. So I cant call it with Selenium.

Comment: Perform this as `Step 1` : `Actions actions = new Actions(driver); actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();` and then `use JavaScript Executor to click on element`.